# Wifi is not working with Ubuntu 14.4

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 14.4 instead of windows (now this is the only OS on my laptop)
I have Broadcom bcm9506 card.
How can I fix this?
I already looked at a lot of similar questions but non of them help me.

```
 lspci -vnn | grep Network
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

Thanks

Comment: post result of running `lspci -vnn | grep Network` in terminal. don't forget post it in [question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/521387/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just run following command in terminal one by one:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo update-pciids
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo reboot
```

<sub>cuted from [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)</sub>